# How to print two responses from one request using python http.client

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, http.client

I am trying to send an request using the below code,

```py
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("localhost")
payload = "GET /_hidden/index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: notlocalhost\r\n\r\n"
headers = {'Host': 'localhost','Content-Length': '56','User-Agent':'-'}
conn.request("GET", "/", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
#ress = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
#data2 = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))
#print(data2.decode("utf-8"))
```

I am expecting two responses from the server and the server is also sending 2 responses but how can I print both of them? if I have an other `conn.getresponse()` I am getting an error. I have attached the server log for a reference both the request sent are accepted in the server but I want to print both the response.
[image: server log]

Comment: Technically is not "one request, two responses" it's "one request, one redirect response, one more request, one response"

Comment: Check [this](https://dev.to/tallesl/following-redirects-with-httpclient-python-module-439j) TLDR is you need to grab the http code and the location header manually to follow it.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding how `conn.request` works, it's not the same as telnet where you would need to type what you have as `payload`, it already does all that for you so you only need the URL

Comment: Use the `requests` module instead of `http.client`. It will follow redirects automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can just follow the request chain

```py
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def get(host, url):
    print(f'GET {url}')

    connection = HTTPSConnection(host)
    connection.request('GET', url)

    response = connection.getresponse()
    location_header = response.getheader('location')

    if location_header is None:
        return response
    else:
        location = urljoin(url, location_header)
        return get(host, location)

response = get('en.wikipedia.org', '/api/rest_v1/page/random/summary')

print(response.read())
```

once you understand the above code snippet. you may then include your specific needs into the code example, such as the code below in the second snippet.

```py
import http.client
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
from urllib.parse import urljoin

def get(host, url, headers):
    print(f'GET {url}')

    connection = HTTPSConnection(host)
    connection.request('GET', url, {}, headers)

    response = connection.getresponse()

    location_header = response.getheader('location')

    if location_header is None:
        return response
    else:
        location = urljoin(url, location_header)
        return get(host, location, headers)
```

call it as such

```py
headers = {'Host': 'localhost','Content-Length': '56','User-Agent':'-'}
response = get("localhost", "/_hidden/index.html", headers)
```

## Extra

learn more about `connection.request` via the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpconnection-objects)

Comment: So, is the `payload` needed or did you just use his code as a base?

Comment: @Daviid you may use the second code snippet. but please look at the first snippet to understand on how to "follow" a redirect

Comment: I'm not the asker, I was just wondering because of my third comment on the question comments.

Comment: @Daviid my mistake lol, yeah no payload is not needed but you can learn more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpconnection-objects)

Comment: fixed, removed the payload from the request